# Printer driver update keeps asking for administrator credentials

Tags: windows-server-2008, group-policy, print-server, shared-printers

I have a Windows 2008 Server with the printer management configured. I share 6 printers with the drivers of the maker. The problem is when I update the printer driver at the workstation, that the user is prompted for administrator credentials.

I have almost all (except 1) of the GPO's configured that are described here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725938.aspx

The problem is that I can't find the GPO **Computer Configuration->Policies->Administrative Templates->Printers** in my Windows Server 2008 Standard. So the other policy (the user config one) is ignored by Windows 7 and Windows 2008.

How to fix this?

Comment: What functional level is the domain?  Have you installed the [2008 R2 ADMX Templates](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=6243)?

Comment: Windows 2008 level. No i didn't. I don't have the R2 version of Windows 2008, so can I install the templates for it on my version?

Answer (score 1):

Did you see that the article of MS is only for W7 and 2008R2.

"Applies To: Windows 7, Windows Server 2008 R2"

"The following procedure assumes that you are using the version of the Group Policy Management Console **(GPMC) that is included with Windows Server 2008 R2**. To install GPMC on Windows Server 2008 R2, use the Add Features Wizard in Server Manager. If you are using a different version of GPMC, the steps might vary slightly."

In http://blogs.technet.com/b/grouppolicy/archive/2009/12/23/how-to-install-rsat.aspx 
"The 2008 GPMC will not have all of the same settings that 2008 R2 / Windows 7 has. If you have moved up to R2 / Windows 7, the Group Policy team strongly recommends only managing GPO's from the R2 / Windows 7 version of the GPMC. Remember, you only need one Windows 7 client to get the newer GPMC!"

you have part of the answer: could you install de gpmc in a Windows 7 and then edit the policy again?